# Add tag to blob using java SDK

Tags: java, azure, azure-blob-storage

I'm trying to add index tags to my data on azure Blob Storage using the java SDK. I need to add tags so I can filter through easier and implement a life cycle policy. When I'm uploading a file, I want that file to be added with a tag key x mapping a value y. I haven't been able to find any useful java documentation, the closest thing I found was [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-blob-index-how-to?tabs=net) in C#. Also, I did find the function [setTags](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/java/api/com.azure.storage.blob.specialized.blobclientbase.settags?view=azure-java-stable) ([this too](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/rest/api/storageservices/set-blob-tags)) which looks like it does what I want, but I've been unable to get this to work (the file seems to be uploaded without the tags). I've tried the following code :

```
String connectStr = System.getenv("AZURE_STORAGE_CONNECTION_STRING");
BlobServiceClient blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClientBuilder().connectionString(connectStr).buildClient();
BlobContainerClient container = blobServiceClient.getBlobContainerClient("tcpblobstorage");
BlobClient blobClient = container.getBlobClient(path + fileName);
Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put("Client", "Client");
blobClient.setTags(map);
blobClient.upload(is, length, true);
```

Note: path + fileName is the path of the new file that is about to be uploaded onto azure.

Anyone have any pointers or ideas of things I might be doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method you would want to use is [`uploadWithResponse(BlockBlobSimpleUploadOptions options, Duration timeout, Context context)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/java/api/com.azure.storage.blob.specialized.blockblobclient.uploadwithresponse?view=azure-java-stable#com_azure_storage_blob_specialized_BlockBlobClient_uploadWithResponse_com_azure_storage_blob_options_BlockBlobSimpleUploadOptions_java_time_Duration_com_azure_core_util_Context_) and set tags using [`BlockBlobSimpleUploadOptions.setTags(Map<String,String> tags)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/java/api/com.azure.storage.blob.options.blockblobsimpleuploadoptions.settags?view=azure-java-stable#com_azure_storage_blob_options_BlockBlobSimpleUploadOptions_setTags_java_util_Map_java_lang_String_java_lang_String__).

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! I'll give it a shot.

Answer (score 4):

I've accepted @Gaurav's answer but if anyone comes looking for it, here is the updated code :

```
String connectStr = System.getenv("AZURE_STORAGE_CONNECTION_STRING");
BlobServiceClient blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClientBuilder().connectionString(connectStr).buildClient();
BlobContainerClient container = blobServiceClient.getBlobContainerClient("tcpblobstorage");
BlobClient blobClient = container.getBlobClient(path + fileName);
Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put("Client", "Client");
BlockBlobSimpleUploadOptions options = new BlockBlobSimpleUploadOptions(is, length).setTags(map);
blobClient.getBlockBlobClient().uploadWithResponse(options, Duration.ofSeconds(30L), Context.NONE);
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use `setTags` after you upload. That works for me.